# Combine all csv file with different date name into one csv file using batch script

Tags: csv, batch-file

Combine all csv file with different date name into one csv file using batch script

I have file csv like this:

```
Alarm2017-03-02_1.csv
Alarm2017-03-02_2.csv
Alarm2017-03-03_1.csv
Alarm2017-03-03_2.csv
Alarm2017-03-03_3.csv
Alarm2017-03-03_4.csv
Alarm2017-03-04_1.csv
Alarm2017-03-04_2.csv
Alarm2017-03-04_3.csv
```

and there is new csv file every minute
with format name like this:
AlarmYYYY-MM-DD_[number sometimes from 1 till 2, or 1 till 4 or 1 till 3 or 1 till 22].csv

how to combine all csv file like that into one using batch script

Comment: See UltraEdit forum topic [Merge / combine / copy the contents of text or CSV files into a new file](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=7118) containing also the most often used command line solution which is for this task `copy /B *.csv Alarm2017.csv` with the advantages (fast, very simple) and disadvantages of this solution.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

what you want is to concatenate the files: see this super-user threaed: https://superuser.com/questions/111825/a-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files